# Meaning of "recursively required from 'function name'" in my auto-returning function

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, auto, type-deduction

I'm aware that C is a statically typed language and all that. But I'm experimenting with its type deduction abilities and I'm confused as to why it gave me a certain message when I ran my code. The idea behind my code is this: I have a Variable class which has the ability to store any datatype, return that data(provided you give its datatype as a template parameter), and return a string indicating the type you stored in it, sort of like Boost's any.
Now, I'm trying to write a `deduce_value()` function which can deduce the value and type stored in the Variable by iterating through a list of given types.

Now this is the code for my value deduction function:

```
/*Null: struct used for when all types
given to deduce_value have been exhausted*/
struct Null{};

/*deduce_value: Recursive value deduction function*/
template <class T=Null, class...X>
auto& deduce_value(Variable& var){
    if (var.holds_type<T>()){return var.get<T>();}//base case
    else{return deduce_value<X...>(var);}//recursive case
}

/*specialized case for when all types
are exhausted and were all wrong*/
template<>
auto& deduce_value<Null>(Variable& var){return var.get<bool>();}
```

The idea is that if the type T is correct, it essentially casts a void pointer to an object to a pointer of type T and then returns its dereference; that's `var.get<T>()`.
Otherwise, it returns nothing until it finds the right type. The `Null` struct and template specialization is just there so that the function has a backup return if none of the types are right.

I know this concept already works when the return type is void and I just `cout` the value, but it's having issues with an auto return.

Comment: What's this `type_name` thing?

Comment: Staring at what's going on in `deduce_value`: looks to me like the operating definition of `auto` there appears to be "type determined at runtime". Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way. What `deduce_value` returns needs to be worked out ***at compile time***, hence your compiler is throwing a temper tantrum. You're trying to have an argument with C++. Any time anyone has an argument with some core fundamental of C++ they will lose and C++ will win.

Comment: "You can skip it as it's not really what im curious about." Writing that is a sign that you should have cut this code down to a [mre]. If the code isn't necessary to understand the question, don't include it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not working is exactly the same as the reason why the following code is not working:

```
auto choose (bool choice, std::string when_true, int when_false)
{
    if (choice) return when_true;
    else        return when_false;
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/51ac33WYo)

`auto` stands for a type. It cannot stand for "`std::string` or `int` depending on a run-time value" because there is no such type in C++. Recursive variadic templates and other fancy metaprogramming things are a red herring.

It *is* possible to have `auto` stand for "`std::string` or `int` depending on the value of a *constant expression*":

```
template <bool choice>
auto choose (std::string when_true, int when_false)
{
    if constexpr (choice) return when_true;
    else                  return when_false;
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rEaGonjdf)

However `var.holds_type<T>()` is not a constant expression, and cannot be made one without making it useless.